# JQuery slide image when hover

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I want to know how to make an 8k width image to move to left when my mouse pointer(not clicking the image, just hover) is in the left side and move to right when it is in the right side using JQUERY, I dont know what the exact name for that effect so i used slide image in the title. if anyone knows how to do this i very much appreciate it... Thanks in advance for those who want to help :D

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to do this. Off the top of my head I would probably have 2 divs inside the image div (1 for each half of the image) and then use the jQuery hover method.

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's 'hover' functionality: http://api.jquery.com/hover/, combined with the mouse position abilities of jQuery, which you can find here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Then set your handlerIn and handlerOut functions based on mouse position over the image.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but here is what I would do. Here is what I would do.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cross-img').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('margin-left', '-8px');
            }, function() {
        $(this).css('margin-left', '0');
    });
});
</script>
```

[See in Action](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/60673975/shared-code/image-hover-slide.html)

Answer (score 0):

You find the position of the mouse using

```
$('img').mousemove(function(event){
    var horizontalMousePosition = event.pageX;
});
```

And then compare that to the image's position on the page

```
var leftEdge = $('img').offset().left //Left edge
var rightEdge = $('img').offset().left + $('img').innerWidth(); //Right edge
var middle = rightEdge - leftEdge;
```

Then if the mouse position is "less than" the position of half the image (ie on the left) then we move it to the left:

```
if(horizontalMousePosition < middle){
    $('img').css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: -=50px
    });
}
```

You'll have to toy around with it because this is all off the top of my head. But all the functionality you need should be there.